# Browser pop up not catched in Katalon Recorder

Tags: selenium, katalon-recorder, katalon

I'm recently used Katalon recorder for automating the online order system. Then, I notice that the browser pop up when adding cart was not catched while I recording the test case for Katalon recorder.

Anyone here who has an idea what are the best things to do? I knew that this pop up messages are not catched by any recording tool like Selenium IDE. By the way, I was advised by my supervisor to look for a tool in automation that has an easy implementation on it.

Looking forward with your response

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaCUx.jpg)

Comment: Chances are that the pop-ups you mention are not actual browser pop-ups but native ones. Could you give some more information on what you are doing any maybe add some screen shots?

Comment: @Andreas kindly check the updated query above.

this contained a successful adding a product

Comment: Which browser are you using? What website is this? If this is a public site, could you please post a link? On Windows, if you need to automate anything beyond Selenium, then AutoIT might be a possibility, but it is quite difficult to say without more information.

Answer (score 0):

An alert is a function which is used to notify users on a Web page. It displays a dialog with a specified message and OK/Cancel buttons.

**First choice you can Handle using Accept Alert**
This alert method is used to confirm an action performed by the user. You can handle this method either in the manual or script modes.

Manual Mode :

```
Step 1: Launching the browser navigating to Alert present page by Open Browser method
Step 2: Maximize the window of the browser with Maximize window
Step 3: Clicking on button
Step 4: Call the Accept alert method
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNETs.png)

**Second choice you can handle using"Switch To…" keywords**

```
1. Switch To Window Title   Switch to the window identified by a given title.
2. Switch To Window Index   Switch to the window identified by a given index.
3. Switch To Window Url     Switch to the window identified by a given URL.
```